# Python3 "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python

I'm using Flask SQLAlchemy models to make a database for my app, and I'm trying to query the database using models.Posts.query.all()
This is my model:

```
class Posts(db.Model):
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(500), index=True)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
    image = db.Column(db.String(500))
    post_body = db.column(db.String(10000),index=True)
    authors = db.relationship('Users', backref='authors', lazy='dynamic')

def __repr__(self):
    return '' % (self.post_id, self.title, self.date, self.image)
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
>>> models.Posts.query.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/lisa-jd/Blog_platform/app/models.py", line 30, in __repr__
    image = db.Column(db.String(50))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Post the whole model here. This line `image = db.Column(db.String(50))` is missing.
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is a bitcryptic but gives an hint:

```
File "/Users/lisa-jd/Blog_platform/app/models.py", line 30, in __repr__
```

your `__repr__` function:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '' % (self.post_id, self.title, self.date, self.image)
```

if called, triggers the infamous message like this simple example shows:

```
>>> "" % 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

you're passing 3 arguments to an empty formatting string. Maybe you meant something like:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '%s: %s %s' % (self.post_id, self.title, self.date, self.image)
```

or with `str.format`

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '{}: {} {}'.format(self.post_id, self.title, self.date, self.image)
```